# How do I populate a dashboard with CSV file

Tags: javascript, python, flask, dashboard

I'm trying to populate [this dashboard](https://themesberg.com/product/admin-dashboard/volt-bootstrap-5-dashboard) with my own CSV files but right now the values are hard coded in. Can any kind soul help provide some guidance on how I can do this?

This is a snippet of the JS that is hard-coded in.

````
    if(d.querySelector('.ct-chart-sales-value')) {
        //Chart 5
          new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-sales-value', {
            labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
            series: [
                [0, 10, 30, 40, 80, 60, 100]
            ]
          }, {
            low: 0,
            showArea: true,
            fullWidth: true,
            plugins: [
              Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
            ],
            axisX: {
                // On the x-axis start means top and end means bottom
                position: 'end',
                showGrid: true
            },
            axisY: {
                // On the y-axis start means left and end means right
                showGrid: false,
                showLabel: false,
                labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
                    return '$' + (value / 1) + 'k';
                }
            }
        });
    }```
````

Comment: There are no values in your "hardcoded" example... Only row / column configuration.

Comment: this `series: [ [0, 10, 30, 40, 80, 60, 100] ]` is the data that is populating the chart. You need to get the data from your csv and format it to this structure and then replace the array in this part with the array of your own data

Comment: Can you show an example of how can I do and which file structure should I place the python code in?